# How do I call a theme function?

Tags: theming, 8

Can someone tell me that how can I call theme function, in Drupal 8, within other hook function?

Of course, we should write hook_theme function.

For example (in Drupal 7): `theme('THEME_NAME')`;

What is wrong in below snippet:

```
function theme_sometheme($variables) {
   $another_theme = array('theme' => 'another_theme_for_test', 'arg1'  => 'value');
   return '<div>'. drupal_render($another_theme) . '</div>';
}
```

Note: Above code is not rendering anything.

Comment: Render array properties begin with `#` - so the `theme` and var keys just needs a leading hash

Comment: There are no theme functions in drupal 8, only theme templates.

Comment: Btw. You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of deprecated `drupal_render()`.

Answer (score 3):

The correct code is using the following line.

```
$another_theme = array(
  '#theme' => 'another_theme_for_test',
  '#arg1'  => 'value'
);
```

That is similar to the following code you find in [`rdf_preprocess_comment()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21rdf%21rdf.module/function/rdf_preprocess_comment/8.2.x). The only difference are the theme applied, and the arguments that theme requires; the way you pass the theme name or its arguments is the same.

```
$variables['author'] = [
  '#theme' => 'rdf_wrapper',
  '#content' => $variables['author'],
  '#attributes' => $author_attributes,
];
$variables['submitted'] = [
  '#theme' => 'rdf_wrapper',
  '#content' => $variables['submitted'],
  '#attributes' => $author_attributes,
];
```

Keep in mind that in most contexts you can just return a render array, which in your case is the following one.

```
[
  '#theme' => 'another_theme_for_test',
  '#arg1' => 'value',
];
```

The necessity to call `drupal_render()` is limited to very specific cases, so most likely you don't need it. If you do, you should use [`\Drupal::service('renderer')->render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/function/Renderer%3A%3Arender/8.4.x) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Drupal 8 you need to build a renderable array in any case so that might solve the trick :

```
$another_theme = [
  '#theme' => 'another_theme_for_test',
  '#arg1' => 'value',
];
```